# How exactly does Javascript instanceof work? Is it slow style?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, instanceof

How does the performance of `instanceof` fair for "huge libraries"?

Does it travel up the prototype chain **one by one**, similar to this? :

```
//..
var _ = john.constructor;
while (true) {
    if (_ === Human) {
        return true;
    }
    _ = _.prototype.constructor
}
return false;
//..
```

Is `instanceof` relatively unperfomant then, compared to storing a unique interface id number in the property of every object.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656957/632951

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah something like that. Here is the relevant part from the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm):

> **[11.8.6   The instanceof operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8.6)**
>
> The production *RelationalExpression*: *RelationalExpression* **instanceof** *ShiftExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *RelationalExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. If Type(*rval*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 6. If *rval* does not have a [[HasInstance]] internal method, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 7. Return the result of calling the [[HasInstance]] internal method of *rval* with argument *lval*.

where *calling the [[HasInstance]] method* is defined as

> **[15.3.5.3   [[HasInstance]] (V)](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8.6)**
>
> Assume *F* is a Function object.
>
> When the [[HasInstance]] internal method of *F* is called with value *V*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If *V* is not an object, return **false**.
> 2. Let *O* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *F* with property name "**prototype**".
> 3. If Type(*O*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 4. Repeat
>      a. Let *V* be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of *V*.
>      b. If *V* is **null**, return **false**.
>      c. If *O* and *V* refer to the same object, return **true**.

Regarding performance: This probably depends on the actual implementations in the browsers. There can be huge differences between them so the best thing would be to make some benchmarks, e.g. with http://jsperf.com/.

---

A problem with `instanceof` is that it might not work if you invoke it on elements from different contexts, such as a frame or iframe. For example, let `a` be an object you can access via `iframe.contentWindow.a` and you want to test whether it is an array, then

```
iframe.contentWindow.a instanceof Array
```

will return `false`.

Comment: That's not a problem, it's a huge benefit!  :) You can mess with `iframe.contentwindow.Array.prototype` and then have "special" arrays!  Or `.Object.prototype` :)

Comment: @cwolves: Which might have unexpected behaviour in the iframe. It is a problem if one does not know about it.

Answer (score 13):

in V8 (Chrome's JS engine), there seems to be little-to-no performance hit:

```
> function A(){}
> function B(){}
> function C(){}
> function D(){}
> B.prototype = new A();
> C.prototype = new B();
> D.prototype = new C();
> 
> var objA = new A();
> var objD = new D();
> 
> var start = (+new Date()); for(var i=0; i<10000000; i++){ objA instanceof A } console.log((+new Date()) - start);
138
> var start = (+new Date()); for(var i=0; i<10000000; i++){ objD instanceof A } console.log((+new Date()) - start);
138
```

Firefox shows identical behavior.

Going a bit crazy here, but:

```
> var classes = [];
> for(var i=0; i<10000; i++){
>   classes[i] = function(){};
>   i && (classes[i].prototype = new (classes[i-1])());
> }
>
> var obj0 = new classes[0],
>  obj9999 = new classes[9999];
>
> var start = (+new Date()); for(var i=0; i<10000000; i++){ obj0   instanceof classes[0] } console.log((+new Date()) - start);
138
> var start = (+new Date()); for(var i=0; i<10000000; i++){ obj999 instanceof classes[0] } console.log((+new Date()) - start);
138
```

I think it's safe to assume there is no performance hit if it can drill through 10,000 classes and not see 1 ms performance difference :)

Comment: going bit crazy is exactly what's required sometimes

Answer (score 7):

According to what Felix Kling quoted, all that instanceof does (excluding the error checks) is to check whether the prototype property(which has to be an object) of the Function can be found somewhere down the prototype chain

```
person instanceof Object
// ROUGHTLY does
return (
     person.__proto__==Object.prototype
  || person.__proto__.__proto__==Object.prototype
  || ... );
```

Here's some pseudocode:

```
person instanceof Person
//ROUGHTLY equals
person.instanceOf(Person)

person.instanceOf = function(Person) {
    if(typeof Person!='object') throw new TypeError;
    if(!([[HasInstance]] in Person)) throw new TypeError;
    return Person.[[HasInstance]](this /* person */)
}


Person.[[HasInstance]] = function(V) {
    if(typeof V!='object') return false;
    var O = this.prototype;
    if(typeof O!='object') throw new TypeError;
    while(true) {
        V = V.__proto__; // [[prototype]] (hidden) property
        if(V==null) return false;
        if(V==O) return true;
    }
}
```