# javascript prototype constructor and instanceof

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

When I checked `instanceof` method, the results are not same .

```
function A(){}
function B(){};
```

First I assigned `prototype` ( reference ) property , into `A`

```
A.prototype = B.prototype;
var carA =  new A();

console.log( B.prototype.constructor );
console.log( A.prototype.constructor == B );
console.log( B.prototype.constructor == B );
console.log( carA  instanceof A );
console.log( carA  instanceof B );
```

The last 4 condition on above returns `true` .

But when I tried to assign `constructor` of B .. results are not same .

```
A.prototype.constructor = B.prototype.constructor;
var carA =  new A();

console.log( B.prototype.constructor );
console.log( A.prototype.constructor == B );
console.log( B.prototype.constructor == B );
console.log( carA  instanceof A );
console.log( carA  instanceof B );
```

On this case `carA  instanceof B` returns `false` . Why it returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer from link .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874372/1722625

`instanceof` actually checking internal `[[Prototype]]` of left-hand object . Same like below

```
function _instanceof( obj , func ) {
    while(true) {
       obj = obj.__proto__; // [[prototype]] (hidden) property
       if( obj == null) return false;
       if( obj ==  func.prototype ) return true;
    }
}

// which always true 
console.log( _instanceof(carA , B ) == ( obj instanceof B ) )
```

if it returns true, `obj` is `instanceof` B